# Legend line thickness in ggraph

Tags: r, ggraph

When using `ggraph`, is there a way to thicken the legend lines for edge color?  I'm trying to override but to no avail.  Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

set.seed(20190607)

#create dummy data
Nodes <- tibble(source = sample(letters, 8))
Edges <- Nodes %>% 
  mutate(target = source) %>% 
  expand.grid() %>% 
  #assign a random weight & color
  mutate(weight = runif(nrow(.)),
         color = sample(LETTERS[1:5], nrow(.), replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  #limit to a subset of all combinations
  filter(target != source,
         weight > 0.7)


#make the plot
Edges %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(vertices = Nodes) %>% 
  ggraph(layout = "kk") + 
  #link width and color are dynamic
  geom_edge_link(alpha = 0.5, aes(width = weight, color = color)) + 
  geom_node_point(size = 10) + 
  theme_graph() + 
  #don't need a legend for edge width, but the color override doesn't work
  guides(edge_width = FALSE,
         edge_color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 2)))
```

[image: Can barely see the legend lines]

My preferred output would look more like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you really want to adjust the `width` aesthetic and not `size`, so that's one little fix.

But the tricky part (at least for me) is because `ggraph` is expanding the aesthetic names automatically, e.g. width >>> edge_width, so you need to use the edge_x format when trying to override the aesthetics in `guide_legend()`.

So you end up with something  like this:

```
Edges %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(vertices = Nodes) %>% 
  ggraph(layout = "kk") + 
  geom_edge_link(alpha = 0.5, aes(width = weight, edge_color = color)) + 
  geom_node_point(size = 10) + 
  theme_graph() + 
  guides(edge_color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(edge_width = 5)),
         edge_width = F)
```

[image]